# Why do I have to use public to expose func with Swift 4 @objc inference

Tags: swift4

Using Swift 4, I have a simple class I wish to expose to Objective-C like this:

```
@objc class SomeClass : NSObject {
    @objc class func foo(someDate : Date) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

After compile the autogenerated Obj-C bridging header does not contain the class. However, if I add the public modifier in front of the class and func and rebuild it will be in the bridging header. This seems to contradict the statement [from Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) that states (emphasis mine):

> Private declarations are not exposed to Objective-C **unless** they are **explicitly marked** with @IBAction, @IBOutlet, or **@objc**

Why do I need to add the public modifier? [Even the Swift docs](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) show examples that leave 'public' off and simply use @objc to expose to Objective-C

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Swift 4.0.3 (Xcode 9.2). Have you tried restarting Xcode and cleaning derived data?

Comment: @Hamish I cleaned and restarted on xcode 9.2, swift 4 and it still does not generate the interface in the Obj-C bridging header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are two different things.

> "Swift declarations marked with the private or fileprivate modifier do
>   not appear in the generated header.

is Followed by

> Private declarations are not exposed to  Objective-C unless they are explicitly marked with @IBAction, @IBOutlet, or @objc.

This can be read as saying a function must have the explicit marking to be *exposed* to Objective-C, **and** (separately) if marked private it will not be included in the header.

I'm not sure why something would need to be exposed without being visible, (I'm not familiar enough with the runtime to speak to that). However the closest Objective-C analogue to `private` is to not be included in the header, so it makes sense to have that behavior match.

Comment: I suspect you are correct, although the docs aren't clear IMHO

Comment: What? Programming documentation not being fully clear and correct? Next you're going to tell me we're bad at time estimates!